# Trying to setup nginx as a reverse proxy for facebook, but getting facebook error

Tags: nginx

my fathers job requires him to use a VPN to access anything work related (emails, websites, etc) outside his office, and the VPN blocks facebook, currently whenever he wants to use facebook, he has to log off the VPN first. He asked me if I could set up something to try and get around that, so I am attempting to setup NGINX on Debian 9 to act as a reverse proxy, however I have very little experience with NGINX. I have found that if I include `proxy_set_header Host    $host;` then I can get to facebook but see
"Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."
But if I don't include it the VPN still blocks facebook.
Any advice?

[nginx config](https://pastebin.com/raw/0fiASV6P)

Comment: This question really belongs on Server Fault  https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Hi, how did you solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to reverse proxy Facebook, for a few reasons:

- `facebook.com` isn't going to load from an alternative hostname, such as `kyles-facebook-proxy-clone.com`.  The browser sends a request header, `Host`.  Facebook's servers won't serve for a hostname that they aren't expecting.
- Undoubtedly there's some client-side JavaScript that will be hardcoded to other hostnames you're not proxying (for API access, CDNs for images/video, etc.) that will break, unless you rewrote the page in your code as well (which isn't reasonably possible due to obfuscation).
- You can't serve traffic for `facebook.com` without having a properly signed certificate for HTTPS.  HTTPS is required for `facebook.com` due to [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).
- Even if you managed to get a certificate, it isn't going to work due to [key pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning).

What can you do?

- Use a proper proxy server.
- [Use Tor](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-over-tor/1-million-people-use-facebook-over-tor/865624066877648/).
- Ask for Facebook to be let through on the VPN.

Comment: so which proxy server would do the job?!